# How can I export/save google maps to SD card on device?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to know if one can save the map with their custom markers to the SD card?  For example:  the user would add several custom markers to the map and then have the option to save (in case the device crashes or something) to the SD card or external storage methods, IE, Dropbox, Onedrive etc?

Is this possible?  and if so could you provide a link (tutorial or documentation)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a snap shot of the map with the markers, or save the marker's current coordinates (lat/long) in database for later use.

Comment: do you mean [static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)?